# How to not mutate a prop variable used as state in a React component without a dummy variable?

Tags: reactjs, state

In order to not mutate state in my React component, I came up with this solution, which works.

However, it seems to have a code smell that I would like to get rid of, i.e. I define the incoming section (JavaScript object) as a dummy varible`section2` which I then use once as the default value to set my state variable `section` which I then use destructuring assignment to not mutate.

**Is there a way to do this without the dummy variable?**

```
interface ICurriculumSectionProps {
    section2: ICurriculumSection;
    searchText: string;
    sectionIndex: number;
}

function CurriculumSection(props: ICurriculumSectionProps) {
    const { section2, searchText, sectionIndex } = props;
    const [section, setSection] = useState(section2);
    const toggleContent = () => {
        setSection({...section, showContent: !section.showContent});
    };
```

Comment: Why is `showContent` not just a separate `useState`? Would that not just make everything simpler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a prop. Props are very frequently used as the initial state when passing a value from a parent down to a child. What you're doing isn't weird at all.

I suppose if you wanted to remove the `section2` variable by simply using the `props` instead:

```
const [section, setSection] = useState(props.section2);
```

But that's still pretty much equivalent to your original code, which doesn't seem smelly at all to me.

You could also consider defining the prop as `initialSection` to make things clearer.

```
function CurriculumSection({
  initialSection,
  searchText,
  searchIndex,
}: ICurriculumSectionProps) {
  const [section, setSection] = useState(initialSection);
```

One thing that *does* look a little bit weird here is the

```
setSection({...section, showContent: !section.showContent});
```

Unless the whole stateful `section` needs to be one cohesive object for use by something *later*, it would make more sense to split off the `showContent` into a different variable, as [React recommends](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#tip-using-multiple-state-variables):

```
const [showContent, setShowContent] = useState(props.initialSection.showContent);

const toggleContent = () => {
    setShowContent(!showContent);
};
```

(but if you have to keep it together in one object, your current approach makes sense)

Comment: Yes, I display many properties of the `section` object in this component. Nice to hear that using a prop as the initial value of a state variable isn't an anti-pattern of sorts as it is certainly useful. The `initialSection` name makes sense. Thanks.